# How to add MSVS2010 into CLion2020.1？

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clion

When i installed MSVS2019,it can be found in CLion Toolchains.
Is CLion2010.1 support compiling C/C++ projects using MSVS2010?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only VS 2013 and later are [supported](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/installation-guide.html#toolchain-reqs)

But the tracker has a feature [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11022) for supporting MVSC2010